# How to get IntelliJ IDEA to make correct indentation of xml tags with attributes on multiple lines?

Tags: android, xml, formatting, intellij-idea

Code:

| - caret

```
<element attr1="1"
         attr2="2"
         attr3="3">|</element>
```

What i expect to see after pressing enter:

```
<element attr1="1"
         attr2="2"
         attr3="3">
    |
</element>
```

What i actually get:

```
<element attr1="1"
         attr2="2"
         attr3="3">
    |
         </element>
```

IntelliJ IDEA CE 11.1

Thank you for any suggestion!

Comment: Have a look at File->Settings->Project Settings->Code Style->XML.  Does it look OK there?

Comment: Everything is fine there. And Code->Reformat Code works fine too (makes code looks like as expected).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known bug reported 3 years ago, [please vote](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-48198).

Comment: Voted :-) So, is there a method to fix it? I find this problem is very annoying...

Comment: You can't fix it, use reformat code until the issue is resolved.

Comment: Does this mean that everyone feels uncomfortable when writing xml? I spend a lot of time to format code and move caret when writing android layouts for example. I that case why there is only 4 votes (with mine, for three years)? Or this bug affects only me? Anyway, thank you for explanation!

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure that many people use IntelliJ as their first choice of XML editor. Until recently, it was very weak compared with other tools such as oXygen.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, neither the output you report nor the output you would like is conformant with the rules in the XSLT/XQuery specification for indentation, here

http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization/#xml-indent

which states:

> Whitespace characters MUST NOT be added adjacent to a text node that
>   contains non-whitespace characters.

The reason is that adding whitespace here could very easily make a document schema-invalid.

Comment: I don't see where this statement is violate, can you give an example of the correct formatted output?

Comment: The content has been changed from `"|"` to `"____|____"` where `"____"` represents whitespace. It's entirely possible that `"|"` is a valid value for the element according to the schema, but `"____|____"` is not.

Comment: "|" is just a symbol i used for position of caret, not a character.